# philosophers of the egoism

Tags: history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-history

some time ago I heard about a sentence that struck my mind.
It was a philosopher quote, like...

> *the world would be a better place if everybody used to be more egoist*

I am looking for the **philosopher** who said that.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: The list of references on the article regarding [psychological egoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_egoism) might trigger your memory. From my perspective, the most famous egoist is likely Ayn Rand and her [Objectivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivism), at least in the US. Also see [SEP: egoism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/egoism/) for more leads.

Comment: unfortunately no luck with those sources... I remember he has a short name, like *Hobbes*, but he is not

Comment: : ( Looks like you're going to have to either surrender or start parsing collections of quotations about egoism. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/egoism. Maybe someone will see this and you'll eventually get a response.